# Wikipedia API sandbox, search by user's input

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp

Trying to search in Wikipedia by user's input but it doesn't work for some reason. First I thought it could be due to cross domain problem. But .ajax should help with that.

Here is codepen: http://codepen.io/ekilja01/pen/pRerpb

Here is my **HTML:**

```
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/43f8201759.js">
</script>


<body>

  <h2 class="headertext">WIKIPEDIA  <br> VIEWER </h2>


  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-10-md">

      <input class="searchRequest blink_me" id="cursor" type="text" placeholder="__"></input>

    </div>

    <div class="searchIcon col-2-md"> </div>
  </div>

<div>
  <p class=results></p>
</div>


</body>
```

Here is my **jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var icon = "<i class='fa fa-search fa-2x'></i>";

  $('#cursor').on("keydown", function() {
    $(this).removeClass("blink_me");
    var searchIcon = $(".searchIcon");

    searchIcon.empty();
    if ($(".searchRequest").val().length > 0) {
      searchIcon.append(icon);
    }






    searchIcon.on("click", function() {
console.log("clicked!");


      var search = $(".searchRequest").val();

      var url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&format=json&search=" + search + "&format=json&callback=?";  

      $.ajax({
        dataType: "jsonp",
        url: url,
        success: function(data) {
          $(".results").html(data[0]);

          console.log(data[0]);
             }

      });
    });
  });
});
```

What am doing wrong? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an error in the order of load for your js.

The `data` object contains the text of the results in the array with index 2, which i assume is what you want to show, change it to

```
$(".results").html(data[2]);
```

You can check a modified version of your original code here

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mRmGXG

Comment: Its a bit wrong $(".results").html([2]) but I got it. Has to be $(".results").html(data[2]. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I forgot to hit the save button, should be fine now.

Comment: Can you please advise me further how to get all 10 results that have been found to be displayed on the page? I guess I have to use for each?

Comment: Yes, you can use $.each(result, function(i, v){ /* add the code to add each result*/});

Depends on how you want to display them.

Comment: Thanks a log. Much appreciated!